# Serializable vs NonSerialized class properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization

I have a class in that there is only properties, the class looks like:

```
public class CmsPage
{

    private int _subjectId;

    public int SubjectID
    {
        get { return _subjectId; }
        set { _subjectId = value; }
    }
}
```

and we can create the class as below also:

```
[Serializable]
public class CmsPage
{

    [NonSerialized] private int _subjectId;
    public int SubjectID
    {
        get { return _subjectId; }
        set { _subjectId = value; }
    }
}
```

AND

```
[Serializable]
public class CmsPage
{
    public int SubjectID
    {
        get;
        set ;
    }
}
```

what is the difference between all three classes?

Comment: What is the scope of your question? There are a number of differences between these classes and the answer will be different depending on your use case. How these classes look to Reflection is very different than how they would look in a SOAP message, for instance. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're after, are you asking about how the Serializable and NonSerializable attributes are used?

Answer (score 0):

- The first example isn't marked with the `Serializable` attribute, and therefore can't be.
- I think in the second the `NonSerializable` attribute is wasted as it is against a private member, but it is serializable as it has the attribute.
- The third is Serializable but is otherwise identical to the others. It is using an expanded form of the autoproperty which could otherwise be written: `public int SubjectID {get; set;}`